# Importing CSV results in NULL values for decimal column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import, values, null-geometry

I am importing a *.csv* file and one of the `"integer"` columns (`"ZVH Density"`) is all NULL values when imported as a Delimited Text file. Whole numbers import (known through trial and error) but decimals (0.03333) do not.

[image]

I have set up a *.csvt* file to define the column as `"Integer"`.

[image]

If I import the file as a Vector, the `"ZVH Density"` column imports, however, it is a String (which I don't want). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The question is confusing. "One of the "integer" columns (...) is all NULL values when imported (...) but decimals (0.03333) do not." How do you expect decimals to import into integer field?

Comment: Could you share couple of rows source data?

Comment: Can you please show your *.csvt* ?

Answer (score 3):

You have a field length of 0, so nothing can be imported. Change field length to a large enough positive value.